# "Paste" button for a textfield using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, text, paste

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and jQuery 1.6.1. I would like to add a button in a form in order to paste in a its field a text previously memorized. That is, I would like that a user that copied a text from somewhere then have the possibility to click on the above mentioned button so that his/her copied text will populate a textfield.

**How can I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only access the clipboard in IE.

For other browsers, you need to [interface with a Flash object](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).

Comment: Maybe the questions was not clear, but I would like to paste the text into a field with the click of a button (and not copy that).

Comment: @user That still requires use of the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

for IE , you can grab the clipboard data .

```
var clipboarddata = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

Comment: Maybe the questions was not clear, but I would like to paste the text into a field with the click of a button (and not copy that).

Comment: when you have the data in the clipboard into a variable , you can use it as you like ..( like alerting it, writing it etc ) ..